# kdenlive Doesn't launch

Tags: ubuntu, shared-library, kdenlive

I just installed kdenlive on ubuntu 18.04 and tried to launch it but I get this error

```
kdenlive: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Svg.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

libqt5svg5 is already the newest version (5.9.5-0ubuntu1).

If someone could give me some suggestion on it.

Comment: Unfortunately users of Debian stable are still stuck with 0.9.10 which is unsupported. maybe this is the reason why i cant launch it

Comment: Are you running Debian or Ubuntu? I never tried to install `kdenlive` on my Debian stable, you can try to install it with `flatpaks` or use an AppImage.

Comment: I am using ubuntu, i installed it using PPA, let me try the appimage.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use snapd, flatpak, or appimage (portable).

- Snapd - https://snapcraft.io/kdenlive
- Flatpak - https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.kdenlive
- Appimage - https://appimage.github.io/Kdenlive/